# Rails, select all files by file type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

for example here i pluck some file names form database

```
> Item.pluck(:item_file_name)
=> ["amqp.dll", "readme.txt", "EULA.rtf", "GPL.txt", "adjperm.dll"]
```

How to select files by type, for example

```
> txt = Item.where(:item_file_name => '***.txt')
and returns
=> ["GPL.txt",  "readme.txt"] #all txt files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is your solution :

> txt = Item.select("item_file_name").where("item_file_name like (?)",
>   "%.txt")

or like this

> txt = Item.where("item_file_name like (?)",
>   "%.txt").pluck(:item_file_name)

Answer (score 0):

try `txt = Item.where("item_file_name like (?)", ".txt%").pluck(:item_file_name)`

Comment: Amar, probably here some syntax error
`SQLite3::SQLException: near ".": syntax error: SELECT "items".* FROM "items"  WHERE (item_file_name like (?).txt%)`

Comment: @user2819006 there needs to be a comma in where clause. `txt = Item.where("item_file_name like (?)", ".txt%").pluck(:item_file_name)` try it.